# Updating Record with incremental file in perl or powershell

Tags: perl, powershell

I have a text file which contains all historical data. From next day i start receiving the incremental files which can have new records as well as the updated records from the historical file.

lets say I have historical data:

```
ID|NAME|COUNTRY
----------
1|BRAD PITT|USA
2|GEORGE CLOONEY|USA
3|RAJESH KHANNA|INDIA
```

Next day i recieve a file

```
ID|NAME|COUNTRY
----------
1|BRAD PITT|CANADA
4|DANIEL RADCLIFFE|UK
```

I want to create a new file with

```
ID|NAME|COUNTRY
----------
1|BRAD PITT|CANADA
2|GEORGE CLOONEY|USA
3|RAJESH KHANNA|INDIA
4|DANIEL RADCLIFFE|UK
```

ID is the key here, delimiter is constant thruoghout the file.

It can be easily achieved with any database tool but unfortunately my new Job needs it to be achieved with Scripting(Perl/Powershell), which I am not very good at.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is that the actual format of the file? Header on first line, `--------` on the next and then rows of `|`-separated columns?

Comment: No i am not getting the headers that is just for the explanation purpose
But yes, '|' is the delimiter

Comment: Import the main CSV using the pipe delimiter and defining your custom header, create a hashtable using the ID property as the keys, import update file, apply updates to hashtable, convert hashtable values to CSV with -notype and using the pipe delimeter, skip the first line, set-content on original file. Done. If it adds in quotes you could strip them after converting to csv.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician : thanks for taking a look at the problem, just one question, can this be automated? Like this is gonna be a daily thing, today's file will act as historical for tomorrow's file.

Comment: @MayankBirthariya I've added an answer that does basically what TheMadTechnician is describing. You could set up a scheduled task that executes the script daily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I wrote perl but it's a very easy language to learn.

The basics of what you want to do are:

1. load original data
2. update original data with new data
3. write out new file

The code to do that is below but should definitely be refactored to suite your direct needs and this isn't a good example if we're looking at large files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $handle;
my @lines;
my $line;
my @file_data = ();
my @columns = ();

open $handle, '<', "/tmp/sample.txt";
chomp(@lines = <$handle>);
close $handle;

# remove header
shift @lines;
shift @lines;

foreach $line (@lines){
        @columns = split("|",$line);
        @file_data[$columns[0]] = $line;
}

open $handle, '<', "/tmp/updated.txt";
chomp(@lines = <$handle>);
close $handle;

# remove header
shift @lines;
shift @lines;

foreach $line (@lines){
        @columns = split("|",$line);
        @file_data[$columns[0]] = $line;
}

# remove blank line
shift @file_data;

open $handle, '>', "/tmp/combined.txt";
print $handle join("\n",@file_data);
close $handle;
```

Comment: Thank You very much, this is what i was looking for.
The only problem i see here if i remove the header from both files the new file will have empty first line.

Comment: you can add "shift @lines" to remove each header line. I thought you had said that the headers weren't there in a previous comment.

Comment: If you haven't done perl in a while, then you should know - it's strongly recommended to `use strict;` `use warnings;` at the start of your code, because that's a way to avoid some more egregious errors. Typically slurping  a file into an array and then iterating it with a foreach loop isn't a good thing, as it's inefficient on memory (and confers no real benefit).

Comment: I would also suggest a hash instead of an array for this.

Comment: I guess the array made more sense to me because it was ordered by ID in the example and a hash doesn't really have an order.

Comment: @Sobrique Ya, thanks for reminding me about strict and warnings. There was some horrible syntax in there. Fixed and updated. Thanks! Nice refresher.

Comment: Depends a bit really - IDs seem sequential in this example so it's a bit of a moot point I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to accomplish this using PowerShell - when you receive a new file, you can parse the new data files easily with `Import-Csv`:

```
$NewData = Import-Csv -Path '.\incomingFile' -Delimiter '|' -Header ID,Name,Country
```

`$NewData` is now an array of objects all having 3 properties named ID, Name and Country with the values from the file.

Assuming that the original file (the file you want to keep updating) is saved in the same format, you'll want to read *that* file into memory as well, using the same technique.

The fastest way to locate the rows that you need to update, is put all the rows from the persistent file into a `hashtable`, using the `ID` property as the key:

```
$OriginalDataTable = @{}
$OriginalData = Import-Csv -Path '.\originalFile' -Delimiter '|'
$OriginalData |ForEach-Object {
    $OriginalDataTable[$_.ID] = $_
}
```

Now, you can use the same approach to loop through the `$NewData` array and assign the values to the correct `ID` in the hashtable with the original data - if the row already exists, it gets overwritten, otherwise it gets added:

```
$NewData |ForEach-Object {
    $OriginalDataTable[$_.ID] = $_
}
```

Then finally sort the values by `ID` and export them back to a file:

```
$OriginalDataTable.Keys |Sort-Object |ForEach-Object {
    $OriginalDataTable[$_]
} |Export-Csv -Path '.\updatedFile' -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for writing it up! I think I'd change the last line to: `$OriginalDataTable.Values | Sort ID | ConvertTo-CSV -Del '|' -NoType | Select -Skip 1 | Set-Content ".\UpdatedFile"` That way you're only iterating the hashtable once for the command rather then once for keys, and then effectively again to expand the values. Plus this way we trim the header row off.

Comment: True, I'll update the import of the original data as well.

Comment: Crap, I just saw that he does want headers. Forget the whole ConvertTo-CSV to Select bit, but piping values to sort to export-csv is still probably faster.